# How to make GetTouch(1) not depending on GetTouch(0) and touchCount

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making an app which asks to keep touch 2 things at same time, but sometimes only one.
So my problem is: GetTouch(1) depends on GetTouch(0) and touchCount.

If I release 1 time the getTouch(0) : getTouch(1) will not be called anymore.

I don't know if I'm clear so here is my code:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                }

                if (Input.touchCount == 2)
                {
                    Touch touch_ = Input.GetTouch(1);
                    if (touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                    {
                    }
                    if (touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    {
                    }
                }
}
```

How can I do to still keep the Touch(1) even without Touch(0) Pressed please ? Just keep doing my stuff during "touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Began".
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you will only be able to access `Input.GetTouch(1)` when the `touchCount` is 2 or greater. You are probably looking for some sort of state variable

```
bool firstPress = false;
bool secondPress = false;
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        firstPress = true;
    }
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        firstPress = false;
    }

    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        Touch touch_ = Input.GetTouch(1);
        if (touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            secondPress = true;
        }
        if (touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            secondPress = false;
        }
    }
}

if (firstPress == true && secondPress == false) 
{
    ...
}
if (firstPress == true && secondPress == true)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need states, just keep doing my stuff during "touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Began" (1) when this one stops: "touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began" (0)

Comment: Then omit ```secondPress = false;``` and check for ```secondPress``` in the ```touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Began``` if condition.

Comment: Ok right, I will try, it looks smart ! Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to make ```secondPress = false;``` when you actually want it to be over

Answer (score 0):

While the `GetTouch` has no guarantee that the same index returns the same touch in the next frame what you can use use the [`Touch.fingerIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html) which is unique for each touch.

So instead of using `GetTouch` you can access the touches via [`Input.touches`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html) and then try to filter out the one for your stored `fingerId` e.g. like

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    if (touch.fingerIndex == storedFingerIndex)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```